# Replace NA with the value closest to midnight

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I have a data frame with time-ordered data.

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "DT   odczyt.1
'2023-08-16 00:00:00'   482
'2023-08-16 23:55:00'   483
'2023-08-17 00:00:00'   484
'2023-08-17 23:59:45'   485
'2023-08-18 00:00:00'   486
'2023-08-18 23:50:45'   487
'2023-08-19 00:00:00'   NA
'2023-08-19 00:01:15'   489
'2023-08-19 23:59:45'   490
'2023-08-20 00:00:00'   NA
'2023-08-20 00:07:00'   492
'2023-08-20 23:59:45'   493
'2023-08-21 00:00:00'   NA
'2023-08-21 07:00:30'   493
'2023-08-21 13:21:45'   495", header = TRUE)
```

**EDIT:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "DT   odczyt.1
'2023-08-16 00:00:00'   482
'2023-08-16 23:55:00'   483
'2023-08-17 00:00:00'   484
'2023-08-17 23:59:45'   485
'2023-08-18 00:00:00'   486
'2023-08-18 23:50:45'   487
'2023-08-19 00:00:00'   NA
'2023-08-19 00:00:45'   NA
'2023-08-19 00:01:00'   NA
'2023-08-19 00:01:15'   489
'2023-08-19 23:59:30'   490
'2023-08-19 23:59:45'   NA
'2023-08-20 00:00:00'   NA
'2023-08-20 00:03:00'   NA
'2023-08-20 00:04:15'   NA
'2023-08-20 00:07:00'   492
'2023-08-20 23:59:45'   493
'2023-08-21 00:00:00'   NA
'2023-08-21 07:00:30'   493
'2023-08-21 13:21:45'   495", header = TRUE)
```

For some days, the value for midnight (00:00:00) is missing. In this case, he would like the value recorded at the hour closest to midnight to appear instead of NA. Sometimes it will be up (earlier) and sometimes down (later). Using `fill` is not effective as NA can be replaced with values down or up.
The last line in should be kept regardless of what time it is written for.

```
> df1.r
                   DT odczyt.1
1 2023-08-16 00:00:00      482
2 2023-08-17 00:00:00      484
3 2023-08-18 00:00:00      486
4 2023-08-19 00:00:00      489
5 2023-08-20 00:00:00      490
6 2023-08-21 00:00:00      493
7 2023-08-21 13:21:45      495
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** OP requested a filtered data frame. Thanks to @Seth for the suggestion the tidyverse implementation.

### base R

```r
date <- df1$DT
missing <- is.na(df1$odczyt.1)
y <- which(missing)
x <- which(!missing)
df1$odczyt.1[y] <- sapply(y, \(a) df1$odczyt.1[x[which.min(abs(date[x] - date[a]))]])
subset(df1, strftime(DT, format="%H:%M:%S") == "00:00:00" | seq(nrow(df1)) == nrow(df1))
```

If there is a tie then the first (i.e. before) value is taken.

**Output**

```
                    DT odczyt.1
1  2023-08-16 00:00:00      482
3  2023-08-17 00:00:00      484
5  2023-08-18 00:00:00      486
7  2023-08-19 00:00:00      489
13 2023-08-20 00:00:00      490
18 2023-08-21 00:00:00      493
20 2023-08-21 13:21:45      495
```

---

### "tidyverse"

This can easily be made into a function for use in a `dplyr` pipeline:

```r
library(dplyr)

fill_by <- function(col, closest) {
  missing <- is.na(col)
  y <- which(missing)
  x <- which(!missing)
  col[y] <- sapply(y, \(a) col[x[which.min(abs(closest[x] - closest[a]))]])
  return(col)
}

df1 |>
  mutate(odczyt.2 = fill_by(odczyt.1, closest = DT)) |>
  filter(DT == lubridate::date(DT) | row_number() == n())
```

**Output**

```
                   DT odczyt.1 odczyt.2
1 2023-08-16 00:00:00      482      482
2 2023-08-17 00:00:00      484      484
3 2023-08-18 00:00:00      486      486
4 2023-08-19 00:00:00       NA      489
5 2023-08-20 00:00:00       NA      490
6 2023-08-21 00:00:00       NA      493
7 2023-08-21 13:21:45      495      495
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, explanations and time. I will just add that my goal is to get ```df1.r``` from my question.

Comment: Hi @GrBa - you could pipe this output to a `dplyr` filter like `filter(DT == lubridate::date(DT) | row_number() == max(n()))`

Comment: I have updated my solutions to subset the data. @Seth thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the distance to the next time and use whichever is smaller. For example

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(DT=as.POSIXct(DT)) %>% 
  mutate(odczyt.1=if_else(is.na(odczyt.1), 
            if_else(DT-lag(DT) < lead(DT)-DT, 
                    lag(odczyt.1), 
                    lead(odczyt.1)
            ), 
            odczyt.1)
  )
```

The `lead()` and `lag()` functions help you get the next and previous values respectively. This returns

```
                    DT odczyt.1
1  2023-08-16 00:00:00      482
2  2023-08-16 23:55:00      483
3  2023-08-17 00:00:00      484
4  2023-08-17 23:59:45      485
5  2023-08-18 00:00:00      486
6  2023-08-18 23:50:45      487
7  2023-08-19 00:00:00      489
8  2023-08-19 00:01:15      489
9  2023-08-19 23:59:45      490
10 2023-08-20 00:00:00      490
11 2023-08-20 00:07:00      492
12 2023-08-20 23:59:45      493
13 2023-08-21 00:00:00      493
14 2023-08-21 07:00:30      493
15 2023-08-21 13:21:45      495
```

Comment: while testing your solution, additional unusual cases were revealed. I edited the question (dataframe). Can you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
df1 |>
  mutate(DT = ymd_hms(DT),
         close_midnight = round_date(DT, "day"),
         time_to_midnight = abs(close_midnight - DT)) %>%
  arrange(-time_to_midnight) %>%
  group_by(close_midnight) %>%
  tidyr::fill(odczyt.1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(DT)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 20 × 4
   DT                  odczyt.1 close_midnight      time_to_midnight
   <dttm>                 <int> <dttm>              <drtn>          
 1 2023-08-16 00:00:00      482 2023-08-16 00:00:00     0 secs      
 2 2023-08-16 23:55:00      483 2023-08-17 00:00:00   300 secs      
 3 2023-08-17 00:00:00      484 2023-08-17 00:00:00     0 secs      
 4 2023-08-17 23:59:45      485 2023-08-18 00:00:00    15 secs      
 5 2023-08-18 00:00:00      486 2023-08-18 00:00:00     0 secs      
 6 2023-08-18 23:50:45      487 2023-08-19 00:00:00   555 secs      
 7 2023-08-19 00:00:00      489 2023-08-19 00:00:00     0 secs      
 8 2023-08-19 00:00:45      489 2023-08-19 00:00:00    45 secs      
 9 2023-08-19 00:01:00      489 2023-08-19 00:00:00    60 secs      
10 2023-08-19 00:01:15      489 2023-08-19 00:00:00    75 secs      
11 2023-08-19 23:59:30      490 2023-08-20 00:00:00    30 secs      
12 2023-08-19 23:59:45      490 2023-08-20 00:00:00    15 secs      
13 2023-08-20 00:00:00      490 2023-08-20 00:00:00     0 secs      
14 2023-08-20 00:03:00      492 2023-08-20 00:00:00   180 secs      
15 2023-08-20 00:04:15      492 2023-08-20 00:00:00   255 secs      
16 2023-08-20 00:07:00      492 2023-08-20 00:00:00   420 secs      
17 2023-08-20 23:59:45      493 2023-08-21 00:00:00    15 secs      
18 2023-08-21 00:00:00      493 2023-08-21 00:00:00     0 secs      
19 2023-08-21 07:00:30      493 2023-08-21 00:00:00 25230 secs      
20 2023-08-21 13:21:45      495 2023-08-22 00:00:00 38295 secs
```